# Watir: undefined method `bridge' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

Whenever I run my feature I get this error:

`$ cucumber features/adopt_puppies.feature`

Cucumber.yml
`default: BROWSER=chrome`

```
Using the default profile...
Feature: Verify total puppies available to buy on website

    Given I am on puppies website       
    # features/step_definitions/adopt_puppies.rb:3
      undefined method `bridge' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/adopt_puppies_helper.rb:4:in `goto_website_homepage'
      ./features/step_definitions/adopt_puppies.rb:4:in `/^I\ am\ on\ puppies\ website$/'
      features/adopt_puppies.feature:4:in `Given I am on puppies website'
```

To fix this I have already downgraded 
`cucumber gem to 2.99.0` and `selenium-webdriver gem to 3.5.0`
but still it is giving same error.

What wrong am I doing?

**Update:**
It got it fixed after adding `hooks` and `env` files but now there is another (similar) error. If I use below line in `cucumber.yml` i.e. I want to use `pretty-face gem (version 0.10.3)`

`default: BROWSER=chrome --no-source --color --format PrettyFace::Formatter::Html --out results/index.html`

Error is same just asking different file to available:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': `require "watir-webdriver"` is deprecated. Please, use `require "watir"`.
cannot load such file -- cucumber/ast/scenario
Error creating formatter: PrettyFace::Formatter::Html (LoadError)
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pretty_face-0.10.3/lib/pretty_face/formatter/html.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `rescue in require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:19:in `rescue in constantize'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:8:in `constantize'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb:211:in `formatter_class'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb:196:in `block in formatter_factories'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb:194:in `map'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb:194:in `formatter_factories'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:197:in `formatters'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:182:in `report'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:72:in `run!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What version of Watir are you running? Also, what is the `adopt_puppies.feature` - is that from Cheezy's book?

Comment: Yes that's from that book. Watir version is 6.16.5. I have updated the description. Maybe that will help to dig into the problem.